# Reference part of a figure (with or without cleveref)

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, cleveref

I have a figure with multiple parts (a, b, c, etc.) and in the text I would like to have a reference to the figure with the letter of the part (i.e. fig 1(b) ).  Is there a way to pass this to `\cref{}` or `\ref{}` in order to have it do this?

EDIT:  So this turned out to be a dumb question.  I forgot `\ref{}` returns just the number, so this is easily done using

```
Figure \ref{fig:1}a says...
```

Comment: There are automated ways of doing this rather than hard-coding the `subfigure` components after your reference.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package to build your subfloats,  in addition to the standard `\ref` command, you can also use `\subref` to reference a particular subfloat. The standard `\ref` command returns a label built by concatenating the float number and
`\thesubfloat`; the `\subref` command only returns the label for the subfloat:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[test1\label{sub:1}]{A}\qquad
\subfloat[test2\label{sub:2}]{B}
\caption{General caption}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{fig:test} and subfigures~\subref{sub:1} and \subref{sub:2}

Figure~\ref{fig:test} and subfigures~\ref{sub:1} and \ref{sub:2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `cleveref` you can use `\crefname`, `\Crefname` to change the default names used for subfigures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{subfigure}{subfigure}{subfigures}
\Crefname{subfigure}{Subfigure}{Subfigures}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[test1\label{sub:1}]{A}\qquad
\subfloat[test2\label{sub:2}]{B}
\caption{General caption}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\Cref{fig:test} and \cref{sub:1,sub:2}

\Cref{fig:test} and \cref{sub:1,sub:2}

\end{document}
```